# Find all strings that do not exist in table column

Tags: mysql

I have a list of 338 strings like the following:

```
013705
013707
013708
013709
```

How do I get all of those strings that **do not** exist in my table/column: `tblclients.clientID`?

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT clientID FROM tblclients WHERE clientID NOT IN (
000100,
000834,
001855,
etc...)
```

But that only returns values from my table that do not exist in my list of strings. I need the opposite: strings from my list, that do not exist in the table. I'm wondering if this is possible with SQL or if I need to use Excel in some way...?

Comment: Do you know min and max possible values upfront?

Comment: @PM77-1 Yes, I just put them into Excel and sorted them. I have the min and the max values (although they are really strings, not numbers, since they start with zero)

Comment: Convert it to a number when you're checking the condition, and do a BETWEEN statement.

Comment: make temporary table and select invert - not in the main table

Comment: Does `select * from (values (1), (2), (3)) x(number)` work in MySQL? If so, that is a road you could go down.

Comment: I guess you don't need that. You just need to check if record exists on Excel side. Do you?

Answer (score 1):

If the numbers that you are testing are in `YourNumbers` then you can run a query like this:

```
SELECT clientID 
FROM YourNumbers y
LEFT JOIN TblClients t ON y.clientID = t.clientID
WHERE clientID IS NULL
```

Comment: The question states that the numbers are not in a table.

Comment: @User15 - I read it that OP wants to find numbers which are not in his main table.  The numbers to compare have to be stored somewhere. My solution uses a temporary table for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same case here...

If the DB supports Common Table Expressions and there are not too many values to check:

```
create table reftable (
   pkey int not null primary key,
   name varchar(40)
);
insert into reftable values ( 101, 'aaaaa' );
insert into reftable values ( 103, 'bbbbbb' );

with checklist as
(
select 101 c1
 union
select 102 c1
 union
select 103 c1
 union
select 104 c1
)
select c1 from checklist
   where c1 not in (select pkey from reftable);
```

Still looking for a better solution...